# Stack Overflow - где кнопка выхода

Tags: поддержка

Где расположена кнопка выхода с сайта StackOverflow (RU)?

Answer (score 6):

Нажмите на бургер в правом верхнем углу и увидите её:

[image: Кнопка выхода]

Comment: никогда не знал, как называется этот элемент

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)